# Exclude folders when using find

Tags: bash, find

I'd like to find all the ".py" file using command:

```
find / -iregex ".*\.py"
```

However, it also list '.py` file from the python package such as django.

How could I exclude specified folders in  'grep' command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-path` option to exclude certain directory paths in your search:

```
find / -iregex ".*\.py" ! -path "/your/django/directory"
```

And you can chain this multiple times if you want to exclude multiple directories:

```
find / -iregex ".*\.py" ! -path "/your/django/directory" ! -path "/another/dir"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "grep -v" to invert the selection.

```
find / -iregex ".*\.py" | grep -v django
```